# NGINX ngx_http_geoip_module, support for MaxMind .dat and .mmdb IP databases

Tags: nginx, maxmind

I've been successfully using NGINX's `ngx_http_geoip_module` with MaxMind's IP databases with the `.dat` extension:

`http {
    geoip_country         GeoIP.dat;
    geoip_city            GeoLiteCity.dat;
    geoip_proxy           192.168.100.0/24;
    geoip_proxy           2001:0db8::/32;
    geoip_proxy_recursive on;`

However, `.dat` is a legacy format. MaxMind now distributes IP databases in `.mmdb` binary format.

Does NGINX `ngx_http_geoip_module` support `.mmdb` format the same way it does `.dat`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ngx_http_geoip_module` does not support GeoIP2, but the third-party module [ngx_http_geoip2_module](https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module) does.